# Does gitlab have a method or API to search for projects by programming language

Tags: gitlab

For example, I want to search for C language projects, and at the same time, I hope that the searched projects can be sorted by the number of stars.

I tried typing C and language:C directly into the search box, but couldn't find anything. At the same time, I also used filenam:C, and it turned out that this global search has been disabled.

Comment: I think this is more suited to Web Applications site

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can search for projects by language and sort my most stars.

In the Explore projects page, you can select the languages you wish to filter on as well as how to sort the results.

Here is the query for C language and sorted by stars: https://gitlab.com/explore/projects?language=6&sort=stars_desc